# Javascript Geo Redirection not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code gives a blank page. no redirection occurs

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
   $.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function(data){

   if (data.countryCode == "CA") { 
     window.location = 'canada.php';
   } else {
     window.location = 'usa.php';
   }    
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Do you get an error running this? I see `})` missing at the end.

Comment: just saw that/ thanks. works now

Answer (score 0):

You script is missing some termination code.

Place this `});` right before the `</SCRIPT>`.

So your code should look like this...

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
   $.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function(data){

   if (data.countryCode == "CA") { 
     window.location = 'canada.php';
   } else {
     window.location = 'usa.php';
   }
   });
</SCRIPT>
```